# Shell Bash - Split Multilne String into Array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to get an Array that contains each string line as an element...

```
stringy=$(ls -l | awk '{print$3,$6,$7,$8,$9}'| grep "$USER")

declare -a myarray=()

IFS="\n" read myarray <<< "$stringy"

echo "${myarray[0]}"
echo "${myarray[1]}"
echo "${myarray[2]}"

for line in "${myarray[@]}"; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

The String looks something like this:

```
brunor Nov 17 17:38 22735
brunor Nov 17 15:38 5391
brunor Nov 17 15:38 5405
brunor Nov 17 15:38 5444
```

(...)

the code outputs just the first element (0) even for the loop:

```
>brunor Nov 17 17:38 22735
>
>
>brunor Nov 17 17:38 22735
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: are you sure this ";" before "do" should be there?  Looks like the ; is making sure the loop only runs once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue is that you're reading `myarray` as a regular variable, not as an array. Use `readarray` instead:

```
readarray -t myarray <<< "$stringy"
```

Other issues include:

- `IFS` is being set to the letter "n" and a backslash, not a linefeed
- `read` defaults to reading a single line regardless of `IFS`
- `echo` is a bad way to check the contents of variables because it's ambiguous (`declare -p myarray` would have immediately shown the problem)